# Unable to import nltk in NetBeans

Tags: python, netbeans, nltk

I am trying to import `NLTK` in my python code and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/afs/NetBeansProjects/NER/getNE_followers.py", line 7, in <module>
    import nltk
ImportError: No module named nltk
```

I am using `NetBeans: 6.7.1`, `Python 2.6 NLTK`.
My NLTK module is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/nltk/` and I have added this in `Python` paths in `Netbeans`.

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might have default python installation on `/usr/bin/python`. So, In Netbeans preference, try to set python interpreter to `/usr/local/bin/python` instead of `/usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

Rectified the problem. I had included the nltk path in the Netbeans global settings but the project was still using Jython 2.5 as its Python platform so the global settings never affected the project.